# Why hasn't this question been reopened yet?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopening

I asked [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199920/creating-words-by-structure), and it was closed because I did not clarify what I meant by the word "randomly". Now I've clarified it but it is not reopened. What is wrong with it now?

Comment: You clarified it, huh? Are you sure it wasn't a volunteer?

Comment: @S.S Anne I clarified the question. PostRockGarfHunter helped me do this.

Comment: I was the one who added the note about "random". You even approved the edit.

Comment: @S.S. Anne PostRockGarfHunter added about some duplicates in the arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Reopening takes time

An unfortunate fact is that this site is not as active as it once was.  That means accumulating the required reopen votes can take a while.

### What you can do

The things I would recommend to do about this are

1. Sandbox your challenge first.  It is too late for this challenge but when a challenge is sandboxed issues can be addressed quickly without needing to attract voters.  You can fix a problem and move on to other improvements very quickly.
2. Do reviews.  If you are upset that reviews are not being done quickly by enough people, it is a good idea to take up the initiative yourself.  Of course this won't help your specific challenge, but I'm sure other people have been in your location and if you all start doing reviews you can help
3. Ping the users that closed it.  People don't always go back and check on things they have voted to close on their own.  If you ping them and explain how you have addressed their concerns they will likely respond with other concerns or vote to reopen.  If no one voiced concerns in the comments then it is a good idea to ask them why they voted to close.  Since you are asking for help please try and provide as much relevant information as possible in the comment.  "I fixed this" will likely appear in their inbox with little or no context requiring some work on their part before they can vote.
4. Post in chat. Posting in places where people go brings the idea to their attention.  Of course the effectiveness of this depends on the activity of these places.
5. Post on meta.  You have already done this, but if the two above options are failing you this can be a place to ask.